# Are there any problems which requires more than double exponential time?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, exponential

Are there any problems, for which all known algorithms require more than double exponential time?

Comment: It's not terribly interesting, but you can get any arbitarty O(f(N)) for any function f(x). Simply by creating a storing a list of all the numbers from 0 to f(N).

Comment: So, for any given O(f(n)) we can construct a problem.

Comment: That is correct, at least in big O terms. Finding interesting problems with uncommon big O's can be a bit harder though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) ensures that problems of this sort exist. As a very contrived example that's used by the theorem, consider the following problem:

> Given a Turing machine M and a string x, does M accept x within 2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup></sup> steps?

This problem provably cannot be solved by a TM in under 2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup></sup> steps, and since a TM can simulate a computer with only an n<sup>6</sup> slowdown, this means that no computer can solve this problem in time o(2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup></sup>).

Granted, this isn't really an *interesting* problem (I can't see why you'd want to solve this except in very contrived situations), but it's known that this problem requires triple exponential time to solve.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Interesting, is there any upperbound, than no problem exist, for which fastest algorithm is faster than that upperbound?

Comment: @user2992539 I'm not sure I understand what you mean - any algorithm gives an upper bound on the runtime needed, so the fastest algorithm can't be faster than the upper bound.

Comment: I was thinking about universal upperbound, that all problems can be solved faster. Maybe something like `(n!)^(n!)^(n!)`

Comment: @user2992539 All problems that can be solved have runtimes that are computable functions. Any function that grows faster than all computable functions will upper bound the runtimes of all problems that can be solved. For example, the Busy Beaver function will upper bound all runtimes. However, by definition, these functions can't be computed and we barely know anything about their runtimes, so it's hard to see if this is useful.